# Creating custom forms (and custom triggered forms/events) for QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qt-designer, qfieldsync, qgis-customization

I'm seriously lost. In QField website, it says that custom forms (at least that Drag and Drop from designer forms are supported) as well as this thread: [QField - create a form for multiple, 1:n photos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394479/qfield-create-a-form-for-multiple-1n-photos)

I would, please, just like an explanation as to HOW do I enable custom forms to function on QField. Merely setting the attribute table setting to provide .ui file in QGIS doesn't change much in QField

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop forms work, NOT custom forms. So ui files make no difference.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. I guess from that creating python events on QField won't be feasible either ?

Comment: No. But SQL Triggers work in PostGIS or SpatialLite or .geopackage.