# QField - adding picture module

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qfield, one-to-many

I'm trying to enable a QField project to take pictures of the features represented by a point layer. In the QGis project I've set a 1:N relation between the point layer and a table using the Relations form (Project > Properties > Relations) (qgis version 3.16.15).
After setting the parent and child layers, I go to the Attributes Form of the point layer (Layer Properties > Attributes Form) to change some parameters and to set the Cardinality, but if I click on the Relation name under the Available Widgets list, nothing appears.
[image]
Where is the error? I'm following [this](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html) and [this](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures/) documentation and also read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366228/setting-qfield-for-1n-photos?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394479/qfield-create-a-form-for-multiple-1n-photos?rq=1) posts. But even considering that my relation could have wrong settings, I can't see any command related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put/drag your point_pics relation into the form layout.